# Making choropleth map using geopandas?

Tags: python

The following python script gives me a choropleth of the maternal mortality rate by country.

The resulting map, though, assigns the same color to (e.g.) Congo and Canada, which is not what the data say. I'm trying to learn how to do this, and I'm stymied by this strange result.

```
import requests
import zipfile
import io
import os
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

mmr = requests.get('http://api.worldbank.org/v2/en/indicator/SH.STA.MMRT?downloadformat=csv')
mmr_zip = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(mmr.content))
names = zipfile.ZipFile.namelist(mmr_zip)
mmr_csv = zipfile.ZipFile.extract(mmr_zip, names[1])
mmr = pd.read_csv(mmr_csv, header =  2)
mmr = mmr[['Country Name', 'Country Code', '2015']]
mmr = mmr.rename(index = str, columns = {'2015': 'mmr'})

# get world shapefile with country borders
world = requests.get('http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.zip')
world_zip = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(world.content))
zipfile.ZipFile.namelist(world_zip)
world_zip.extractall()
world_map = gpd.read_file('TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.shp')

merged_map_mmr = pd.merge(world_map, mmr, left_on = 'ISO3', right_on = 'Country Code')
merged_map_mmr.plot(column = merged_map_mmr['mmr'], cmap = 'RdYlBu', scheme = 'QUANTILES', figsize = (10, 8))
```